# has_many with two or more tables.

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, hash

I'm trying to add multiple has_many relationships to my model:

```
class Program < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :courses, :program_offers
  belongs_to :university
  attr_accessible :end_date, :name, :period, :start_date, :symbol, :year, :university_id, :description, :titles, :profile, :price
end
```

But I get:

`hash expected` error.

How can I reference two has many tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that because it is association method which takes only one association name as argument:

```
  has_many(name, options = {}, &extension)
```

So specify each association in `single line`.

```
  has_many :courses
  has_many :program_offers
```

If you specify like that it considers that you are specifying some condition or block. See the API doc http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_many

Comment: I can't place them all in a single line?